# Render child component over parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to render component with another route but this component must not cover all page. For example, I clicked on some question from stackoverflow list, and than I will receive animate from right to left modal, and I need to change route also

[image]

React router (I am using V4)

```
export default (
  <Switch>
    <App>
      <Route exact={true} path="/" component={App} />
      <Route exact={true} path="/product/:id" component={Product}/>
    </App>
  </Switch>
);
```

My product container looks like

```
export default function productContainer(ChildComponent) {
  class ProductContainer extends Component {
    render = () => {
      return <ChildComponent/>
    }
  }

  return ProductContainer;
}
```

And my product component

```
class Product extends Component {
  render = () => {
    return ("")
  }
}

export default productContainer(Product);
```

When I emulate situation, which I describe above, my page fully rerendred and I don't see my App component Page

Have any idea, how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People have asked how to render a modal as a route before in react-router without re-rendering (can't find the discussion right now). Essentially with react-router this is not possible. Each route change causes a re-render. That said, you can do what you want by nesting your routes.

Each component can return routes, so by using composition you can choose where to render any route.

For instance,

```
export default (
  <Switch>
    <App>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </App>
  </Switch>
);
```

Inside `<App />` -

```
render() {
    return (
        <Something>
            <PageHeader />
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/product/:id" component={Product}/>
            </Switch>
        </Something>
    );
}
```

So you can see, if you were to add your routes inside the `App` component, they can all share a common page layout.

Remember: Any component can return multiple routes or just a single one inside a Switch! Switch will only render the first route that matches.

Also Remember: Routes inside a switch must be a direct child, you can't have `Switch -> App -> Route`, it must always be a direct child like `Switch -> Route`

Answer (score 0):

Use render property instead of component in Route.

```
<Route exact={true} path="/" render={() => (
   <div>
      <App />
      <Route exact={true} path="/product/:id" component={Product}/>
   </div>
)} />
```